How come my for loop won't go through all elements of a list?
I want my for loop to remove all items in a list that also occur in another list, but it's only deleting the first identical item, and not the rest.
My code currently looks like this:
current_word = ['m', 'e', 'o', 'w']
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

def de_vowel(current_word):
    for letter in current_word:
        if letter in vowels:
            current_word.remove(letter)
    print(blank.join(current_word))

de_vowel(current_word)

I expected the code to print "mw" but it printed "mow." Although it did remove 'e', it didn't remove 'o' even though it's in the vowels list. I don't understand why the for loop isn't working.

You can't modify a structure that you're iterating through.  The for statement keeps a position in the list, and when you modify the list, the position is out of date.  Instead, create a NEW list with the items you want to keep and leave the original list alone.
